# runtime requires function imports which are not present on the host: 'env:_critical_section_1_0_acquire', 'env:_critical_section_1_0_release'

Tags: runtime, host-functions, runtime-interface

I wanted to add a runtime interface, which can be simplified to the following:

```rust
#[sp_runtime_interface::runtime_interface]
pub trait Test {
    fn some_bytes() -> Vec<u8> {
        vec![]
    }
}

fn get_instance() -> Instance {
    static INSTANCE: once_cell::sync::OnceCell<Instance> = once_cell::sync::OnceCell::new();
    INSTANCE
        .get_or_init(|| {
            Instance::expensive_new(&test::some_bytes())
        })
        .cheap_clone()
}
```

I then added it to host functions and got this when tried to run the runtime:

> Cannot create a runtime error=Other("runtime requires function imports which are not present on the host: 'env:_critical_section_1_0_acquire', 'env:_critical_section_1_0_release'")

Note that those are not the functions I added and look like functions related to atomic operations. When removing `once_cell`, everything starts to work again, but I'm not sure how do I provide those functions.

I'm quite puzzled right now. The goal here is go get large (4.5MiB) blob of bytes available in the runtime, then instantiate a data structure from those bytes (that is relatively expensive to do) and cache it for future use (cloning is cheap).